# What is the way to check all items in a outletcollection for a value

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to go through a few controlled  segments making sure all have been clicked before going to the next view.

so far I have this:

```
-(void)checkAllSegments
{   BOOL alertShown;
    alertShown = NO;
    for (UISegmentedControl *swItem in allSegmentControlOutlet) {
        int selectedSegment = swItem.selectedSegmentIndex;
        swItem.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
//didPass = YES;
        if (selectedSegment == -1) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fill in all forms"
                                                            message:@"Please go back and fill in missing info"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

           // [swItem setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            if (!alertShown) {
                [alert show];
                alertShown = YES;
                didPass = NO;
                return;
            }

        }


    }
    if (didPass) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToHiring" sender:self];
        }
}
```

The problem is I dont know where to put `didPass = YES;` because where it is commented out it kind of works unless the last item in the loop is filled. Or maybe there is a better way to check all values in a collection that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `didPass = YES` at the beginning of your method (before the for loop).

Then iterate over your outletCollection. As soon as you find an unclicked element set didPass to NO.

Comment: hmm that seems to work, I coulda swore that I tried that, thanks for the simple answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is already answered, but here is a cleaner way to achieve the same:

```
// Check all controls and get the minimum selectedIndex
NSNumber *minIndex = [yourCollection valueForKeyPath:@"@min.selectedSegmentIndex"];
if ([minIndex isEqual:@(UISegmentedControlNoSegment)]) {
    // At least one control is unselected
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I figured there had to be a nicer way! +1